# Modification procedure with cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is a procedure with a cursor:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Task_cursor
    @task_cursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS 
    SET @task_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
        SELECT Name, Birth_Year
        FROM Lab6.Students;

    OPEN @task_cursor;
```

And function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FunctionTask2 (@StudentID INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @ret INT;

   SELECT @ret = Faculty_ID + 10
   FROM Lab6.Students
   WHERE PK_Student_ID = @StudentID

   RETURN @ret
```

END;

I need to modify (`ALTER`) the procedure, so that there would be a column in cursor with variables from function

Comment: Running a function within a cursor loop will give you poor performance. Would you be willing to consider a JOIN in your original query, or is there a reason that you really want a function?

Comment: Whoa!!! Why do you have a procedure with a cursor as an output variable? This just absolutely screams of a design gone horribly wrong. And if this is for a class you should tread lightly as this approach should never be used in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Task_cursor
    @task_cursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS 
    SET @task_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
        SELECT Name, Birth_Year, dbo.FunctionTask2(PK_Student_ID)
        FROM Students;

    OPEN @task_cursor;
```

By the way, I agree with the other two that this is not a great design, but I will assume you have your reasons.